# database of countries and cities

Tags: ios, database, iso, countries

it's been several days I'm looking for a database of countries and cities around the world but I can not find anything. I want to use it in the form of my application.

Answer (score 2):

For countries there is the [ISO 3166 list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1).
Not sure about cities though.

**EDIT:** After a quick google I did find the *free* [MaxMind World Cities with Population](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities).